# DC analysis of a CMOS comparator

Tags: dc, cmos, comparator, virtuoso

I'm designing a strongarm latch comparator in virtuoso using gpdk90 and I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong while doing DC simulations. I want to extract the comparator's offset but the output is acting weird, as if the circuit is not working. Transient analysis shows it's working as it should. Am I missing something?

[image: This is the testbench I'm using]
[image: Comparator circuit]
[image: Dc Analysis]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.